# How to remove a strange border in css

Tags: html, css, border

I was trying to make a [border, but there is always a strange border appear under it, I was try to see what happened and I found there is a "shadow root" and there is a strange div there but I cant remove it, can someone help me? thanks

Picture of the strange border appearing:

[image: strange border]

I found a strange div and shadow root here (I don't write this div and shadow root)

Picture of the strange div:

[image: strange div]

Comment: You need to provide some code (Not as screenshot) so we can replicate the same problem as you.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not having trouble understanding your question, but it would be better if you provide some code with index.html also!

The main thing as far as I see, that you need to try write styles in CSS code using classes or id instead of a simple tag element. Just try to code in that way to fix that problem

```
.myDiv{
/* your styles here */
}
```

instead of

```
div{
   /* your code here */
    }
```

your index.html must look as follows

```
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

class, which referred to div you want to be edited

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it is due to the Chrome extension Scrnli. Disable it and you will see how that border disappears.
In my case I do not uninstall it because it is quite useful and free, but there is some kind of conflict in the iframe that it generates.

I hope I have been of help to someone with the same problem.

Regards.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the asker has the same extension?

Comment: Yes, the que extension icon is in the topbar

Comment: Ah, sorry then.